# Automatic refresh when launching activity

Tags: android

In my application I have a activity that displays some web content from database..... I just want to know how can I  refresh the activity (Only One time).....

Please suggest and provide some code block if possible.

Comment: Use postdelay method inside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh activity at any time, just use :

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

If you don't want to see the animation, do this :

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
```

If you want to do this after a certain time :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms like refresh activity
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //Do refresh after 100ms
      onRefresh();
    }
}, 100);
```

After that I successfully auto refresh after 10ms.